# Legal enum usage in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums, singleton

Recently I have started to use python3 and found out that there is built-in `Enum` type and it is possible to use it like it is used in Java, say for singleton creation. I can load a config of my telegram bot like this:

```
class Config(Enum):

    DATA = 'data'

    def __init__(self, dummy):
        with open('./app/config/data.yml', 'r') as f:
            self.__data = yaml.load(f)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        """
        May be too expensive, but config should not be mutable
        so it returns a defensive copy for mutable sequences. 
        :param item: requested item
        :return: value of the item
        """
        value = self.__data[item]
        return deepcopy(self.__data[item]) if isinstance(value, (MutableMapping, MutableSequence)) else value

    @property
    def authorized_url(self):
       return '{}/bot{}'.format(self['base_url'], self['token'])

    @property
    def updates_url(self):
       return self.authorized_url + self['endpoints']['get_updates']

    @property
    def send_message_url(self):
       return self.authorized_url + self['endpoints']['send_message']
```

I assume it appropriate as config is a kind of a singleton, and I don't have to bother with instance creation. It is created automatically during module import and encapsulated inside of the class. So I get everything just out of the box, plus I can define handy methods for aggregation of values.

So I am curious whether it is OK to use enums like this in python?
If not, I would like to hear why not.

Comment: Don’t use double-underscore prefixes; a single underscore is private by convention.

Comment: Single underscore is supposed to indicate a protected attribute while double underscore means "private".

Comment: No, a double underscore means “I’m trying to apply Java to Python”. Avoid. Avoid singletons, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not the purpose of enums.  This is using a side effect of enums to do something else entirely.

> .. and I don't have to bother with instance creation.

Instance creation in this case is **one** line of code:

```
my_config = Config()
```

And the inclusion of this one line would allow the elimination of one line, as this:

```
from enum import Enum
class Config(Enum):
```

becomes simply:

```
class Config():
```

So this construct actually requires more code to express, and seems to be rather overdone.  If I ran across this in a code review I would reject it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But enum also ensures that there is the only limited number of  instances of the class i.e. it is a singleton. In what you suggest, it is possible to create as many instances as one would like to.

Comment: There is a python adage that goes: "we're all adults here". Which is to say that in general python does not provide mechanisms to force programmers to not be silly.

Comment: I agree. Seems like I overdone it. Thanks for the explanation!